# Porque não consigo ver o código do ícone (❌) no modo desenvolvedor?

Tags: html5, unicode

Exemplo desse ícone: ❌

No modo desenvolvedor (F12, Google Chorme), não consigo ver qual o código desse ícone, aparece somente imagem. Porque isso acontece ? Tem algum segredo ?

Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao invés de mostrar imagem (❌), não deveria mostrar o código "&#10060" ?

Comment: Como assim, código? O símbolo é um carácter normal.

Comment: @LINQ está me dizendo que esse ícone é um caractere ? Tem um link que mostra todos os códigos de cada ícones: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#note4

Comment: É um carácter Unicode, [neste link tem todos](https://unicode-table.com)

Comment: @MatheusMiranda vai no console e coloque `'❌'.charCodeAt();` o retorno será `10060`  que é o código: `&#10060`

Comment: @NoobSaibot que bizarro, isso eu não sabia !!!

Comment: Porque não mostra o código no modo desenvolvedor ? Exemplo: &#10060, não deveria mostrar "&#10060" no modo desenvolvedor ?

Comment: @LINQ não deveria mostrar "&#10060" no F12 ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Aí só quem fez o browser que pode responder, mas ao meu ver não deveria. A letra `a` mostra o código 97 no recurso citado?

Comment: @LINQ, Sim, como o código 97

Comment: Não sei se entendi. Você tá dizendo que quando clica F12 (no inspecionar elemento) todos os carácteres são apresentados como códigos unicode?

Comment: @LINQ, eu entendi errado, na verdade mostra como `a` mesmo.

Comment: @LINQ então a letra A é a mesma que ❌ ?, ou seja os 2 são do tipo caractere. Estou tão confuso.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda NÃO! Ambos são carácteres, bem como ன, ᄧ, ᖄ, e vários outros

Comment: @LINQ matou minha dúvida. Eu achava que esse ícone era outra coisa.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Ótimo! Estamos aí pra isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para esse caso, é utilizado o padrão Unicode (note que [não é um encoding](http://[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)])). De forma simples, é um mapeamento de chave e valor entre caracteres e seus códigos Unicode (ou [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)).

Assim como no screenshot que você postou, todos os caracteres do nosso alfabeto são mostrados normalmente, assim são os emojis. No Unicode, tanto a letra `a` quanto o  são caracteres.

```js
console.log(`a == ${'a'.charCodeAt()}`)
console.log(` == ${''.charCodeAt()}`)
```

A maior aplicação do Unicode é poder suportar vários alfabetos como o latino, grego, glagolítico, cirílico e outros utilizando o mesmo padrão.

Segundo o [W3](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-who-uses-unicode), **todos** os browsers, sistemas operacionais modernos, e os encodings utilizam Unicode internamente.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Pense no Unicode como uma grande tabela: para cada caractere, existe um número correspondente. Para a letra `a`, o número é 97, para o emoji "carinha sorridente com óculos", é 55358, para o "X vermelho" é 10060, etc. A diferença é que os emojis permitem uma maior liberdade para serem representados de milhares de jeitos diferentes - é só ver como cada emoji tem um desenho diferente em cada sistema, por exemplo; o código unicode (o número) é o mesmo, mas a representação (o desenho) varia. Para saber mais, veja [este artigo](https://bit.ly/2ibBNoI)

Comment: @hktsubo bom saber, vou ler nesse artigo e matar todas as minha dúvidas, obrigado !